# EventToCommand issue when upgrading from vs2013 to vs2015

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I've recently upgraded from vs2013 to vs2015. My project is WPF based, using the mvvm light libraries. However, I'm getting the following design time error with the mvvm light EventToCommand:

cannot add instance of type eventtrigger to a collection of type triggercollection. Only items of type T are allowed

This only happens when running my application through vs2015. (I've updated my sln and project files from 12 to 14).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:command="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"

<i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding OnLoadingCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unloaded">
            <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding OnClosingCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: when you open the project in `vs2013` and look at the `TargetFramework`  when right clicking on the `project->properties` what version of .net does it show.. make sure that `vs2015` has at least the `4.0 || 4.5`

Comment: They're both targeting 4.5. Thanks anyway.

Comment: could this be a dll issue meaning that vs2015 is not backwards compatible ? contact Microsoft's support

Comment: I remember mvvm light is open source project ? download the source of EventToCommand and see what's vs2015 complaining .... for making sure, please perform clean solution and remove everything in bin folder first